# Derive a model class from default entity model class in Database first approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first

My question on very first instance may not give an impression what I am seeking here. Please read the elaboration here.

I am working on creating RESTful services using MVC 4 solution with Web API template.

To establish SQL database connection, I used Entity framework DB-first approach.

The table from which I like to read values is having 45 columns. And in my requirement is to read only two columns out of it. Can I omit rest all columns somehow ? Is there a way to derive a class out of that entity model class ? Or is there a way to filter the final object?

I welcome any suggestions or directions here.

Answer (score 2):

Create a view model for your two properties and use a projection to populate the object.

new class

```
    public class ApiModel
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }
    }
```

return the new class

```
return dbContext.<your entity name>.Select(s => new ApiModel
{
    Property1 = s.Property1,
    Property2 = s.Property2
});
```